# How to play UILocalNotification sound while do not disturb mode is on?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, uilocalnotification

I can't seem to find a way to play the local notif sound when do not disturb is on, it's for an alarm clock app so it's kind of essential that the sound play even when do not disturb is on. Is there anyway around this?

As another option I've considered having a blank audio play in the background until I need the alarm called, but I've heard that Apple would reject this method.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why would you need to play when the phone is in do not disturb mode? Chances are that if the user wanted to hear the alarm they would disable the do not disturb mode. I don't think there is a way to get around your problem.

Comment: I'm trying to create an Alarm clock app, I'm using photo recognition to turn it off, but I can't get the sound to work

Comment: The ios default alarm clock does sound in do not disturb, so it would be useful to know how to replicate that effect. For example, imagine a pomodoro timer to track focusing time, you'd like to set do not disturb to silence all other notifications except the pomodoro app.

Comment: I need notifications that can bypass it to receive forex/crypto market alerts. Apple should provide some way to allow apps the permission to toggle on/off.